# Fourier series of $f(x)=\sin^2x\cos^2x$ at $(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-series

Find Fourier series of $f(x)=\sin^2 x \cos^2 x$ at $(-\pi,\pi)$

$f(x)$ is even so we only have to evaluate $a_0,a_n$

$$
a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}
      \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sin^2 x \cos^2 x dx
    = \frac{1}{4\pi}
      \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2(2x)
    = \frac{1}{4\pi}
      \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{2} dx
    = \frac{1}{4}
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}
a_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}
       \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 x \cos^2 x \cos(nx)dx\\
    &= \frac{1}{4\pi}
       \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos(2x)\cos(nx)}{2}dx\\
    &=\frac{-1}{16\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(\cos((n+2)x)+\cos((n-2)x))dx\\
    &=0
\end{split}
$$

So $f(x)\approx\frac{1}{8}$

Is it correct?

Comment: @gt6989b why $a_{2n}$? it is an even function so it is just $a_0$ and $a_n$

Answer (score 6):

Simply write 
$$\sin^2x\cos^2x=\dfrac14\sin^22x=\dfrac18-\dfrac18\cos4x$$

Answer (score 3):

As a more effective way we have that

$$
\begin{split}
f(x) &= \sin^2 x \cos^2 x=\frac12(1-\cos 2x)\cdot \frac12(1+\cos 2x) \\
     &=\frac14(1-\cos^2 2x)=\frac14\left[1-\frac12\left(1+\cos 4x\right)\right]=\frac18-\frac18\cos 4x
\end{split}
$$

Using the same expression in the integral obviously we obtain

$$a_n= \frac{1}{\pi}
       \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 x \cos^2 x \cos(nx)dx= \frac{1}{\pi}
       \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(nx)\left(\frac18-\frac18\cos 4x\right)dx=$$

$$= \frac{1}{8\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(nx)dx-\frac{1}{8\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos(nx)\cos 4xdx$$

which is equal to $-\frac18$ for $n=4$ and equal to $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So I have an error as you have cosine, but $a_n=\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 x \cos^2 x \cos(nx)dx=0$

Comment: @newhere Using the same expression for the integral we see that, obviously, $a_n=-\frac18$ for $n=4$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise.

Comment: How do you see it? I got $0$ for any $n$

Comment: @newhere I've added that in the answer.